# error in JSX file: gon is not defined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

I'm trying to use [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) with React.js. At first, I only used Gon to pass static data, and it worked! But in the case of using Ajax(jquery) in jsx file, it throws an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: gon is not defined
```

In my controller, you can see two functions:

`share` is a action of form, so it can pass static data to the new page correctly.

`search` is called by Ajax, it can't pass the dynamic data back to current page.

```
  def share
    @curiosity = Curiosity.friendly.find params[:curiosity_id]
    gon.curiosity = @curiosity
  end

  def search
    @curiosities = Curiosity.where("title like ?", "%#{params[:keyword]}%")
    gon.curiosities = @curiosities
    render json: gon.curiosities
  end
```

In my **application.html.erb**, I've tried two versions, both won't work:

```
<head>
...
<%= include_gon(init: true, watch: true) %>
<%= Gon::Base.render_data({}) %>
```

and

```
<%= include_gon %>
```

Last, in my **.js.jsx** file:

```
$.post( 
  this.props.url, 
  { keyword: $("#searchKeyword").val() },
  function(data) {
    console.log(gon.curiosities);
    console.log(data);
  }
);
```

Obviously, I have tried [`gon.watch`](https://github.com/gazay/gon/wiki/Usage-gon-watch) but it doesn't work either! Any suggestions?